# Get access to smartphones camera antibanding algorithm

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, vulkan

i try to write an App that can detect light frequencies (between 50-200 hz) of captured light sources by the device camera in real time. The ultimate goal is to manually adjust the shutter to specific detected frequencies.

Iam currently using Android NDK together with Vulkan API.

I know the device already does something like that with the internal "AntiBanding algorithm" to adjust the shutter and remove/reduce banding artifacts.

There is even a debug output in logcat showing this function in action.

#Logcat output:

```
2022-07-11 11:26:54.027 26962-30674/? I/AntiBanding: FlickerSetDetectInfo(), flk : type = 1, freq = 0, m_f = 12, res = 91, var = 0.000000, avg = 9, dep = 100
```

What i tired so far:

A. Using the device internal Ambient Light Sensor. Unfortunatly i could not get more than 3 hz sample rate out of the sensor which makes sense i think because that is not its intended usecase.

Iam not really an Android guy so my questions are:

1. Is there any way to get access to this function?
2. Which sensor hardware is used for the AntiBanding detection ? (Current test device: Huawei P40 Pro)

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in this one:
[Android API for getting available antibanding modes for your camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics#CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_ANTIBANDING_MODES)

Comment: Thank you. I know about that function. Unfortunatly this only sets the the Antibanding Mode to fixed either 50/60 hz or OFF which wont help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested this as this might otherwise interfere with what you want to do so I'd had turned it off...